# Does insurance cover injury playing rec sports

Tags: canada, insurance

If I get hurt playing recreational soccer after work, will my employer insurance cover my medical/hospital expenses?

Comment: What is your basis for questioning this? If you purchase insurance through your employer, it is **your** insurance.

Comment: Ok thanks i thought it will only cover work related injury.

Comment: That's Worker's Compensation insurance coverage, which is something your employer must pay for, and they provide it at no cost to you. Health insurance is a separate entity

Comment: We're on our way to addressing this via comments only. @Noah, you want to enter as a full answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific insurance contract that must be read in order to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're confusing "Worker's Compensation Insurance Coverage" for "Supplemental Medical/Health Insurance"

Per your comment: Worker's Compensation coverage is coverage that your employer is (usually) required to obtain. This covers you during work-related injuries and is of no cost to you.

Medical / Health Insurance coverage is coverage that you purchase for yourself (and optionally, your dependents). This can be purchased independently, or can be purchased through your employer. However it's purchased, it is your coverage to use. You should take some time to familiarize yourself with the plan that you purchased, and its coverage, and your liability under the plan.

**EDIT**: Assumptions were for U.S. (sorry for not inquiring about your location). Answer has been updated to reflect a less US-specific response. Canada does have laws regarding Worker's Compensation, though. Might want someone with Canadian expertise to chime in.

**EDIT 2**: Per @ChrisInEdmonton's comment, I've updated terminology to reflect Canadian products

Comment: I believe the OP is in Canada, worker's compensation AFAIK is a US term.

Comment: @littleadv Good point. UPDATE: Canada has mandatory worker's comp, as well

Comment: Your assumptions fit for Canada if you change "Medical/Health insurance" to "Supplemental medical/health insurance", as far as I understand it. :) I live in Canada.